# Inconsistent behavior for rendering cards on android and ios

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I am displaying adaptive cards on android and ios. On android device I had issues with text getting truncated. So, I added the "wrap" property but that causes an alignment issue on the cards as can be seen in the below image.

[image: card]

In order to fix the alignment issue, I updated the card template to display each line item as a row using columnset for each of the lines. Please find the template below

```
{
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                "content": {
                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "body": [
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "medium",
                                            "weight": "bolder",
                                            "text": "August 2022 bill",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "medium",
                                            "weight": "bolder",
                                            "text": "£83.46",
                                            "horizontalAlignment": "right"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "size": "small",
                            "text": "From 28/07/2022 to 29/08/2022",
                            "spacing": "medium",
                            "separator": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "size": "small",
                            "text": "0123456789",
                            "spacing": "small"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "Tariff charges",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "£20.00",
                                            "horizontalAlignment": "right",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "Minutes",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "£0.55",
                                            "horizontalAlignment": "right",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "Messages",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "£0.30",
                                            "horizontalAlignment": "right",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "Charges when abroad",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "£2.30",
                                            "horizontalAlignment": "right",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "Premium & Information services",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "£1.65",
                                            "horizontalAlignment": "right",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "ColumnSet",
                            "columns": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "Balance brought forward",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Column",
                                    "width": "stretch",
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "TextBlock",
                                            "size": "small",
                                            "text": "£58.66",
                                            "horizontalAlignment": "right",
                                            "wrap": true
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

After updating the template, the data gets truncated on iOS device and displays well on Android. Below is the image for iOS

[image]

I am unable to figure out the inconsistent behavior across devices. Is there any specific property that causes this behavior(IMO it should have similar behavior across devices).

Or is there any better way to do this to avoid inconsistencies across devices?

Comment: Given the issue seems to change/shift between devices and from one setting to another, I'd say this is specific to adaptive cards. I'd suggest you post this on the [Adaptive Cards](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/) repo as an issue and see what traction you get there. As a workaround, you could try detecting the device type (or some other identifiable property) and send the adaptive card that works for that device.

Comment: @StevenKanberg I am faced with similar issue while using choice prompts with hero cards [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74044453/adding-prompt-options-hides-text-on-android-devices) . Any idea if this has also to do something with device setting?

Comment: Well, it's worth investigating. Given this issue hasn't been reported by others, that is certainly a reasonable thought. But I am not familiar with device settings well enough to know what might be the cause. Certainly any other CSS in the hosted page/app could be inadvertently affecting it, as well. All things worth checking.

Comment: You could try changing the manifest version for the adaptive card to the most recent stable version, 1.5, and see if that makes a difference. There is also the preview version, 1.6.

Comment: Also, what is the client being used? Is this customized Web Chat in a browser or in an app or something else?

Comment: @StevenKanberg This is being used in an app. I will try changing the version for the adaptive card to check the behavior.